# What does the suffix #DEN mean on the value of a variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

When debugging in VS2005 I have a float in the Locals window whose values is:
`1.744e-039#DEN`

What does the `#DEN` signify/stand for?

Comment: Applies also to more recent editions of Visual Studio (e.g. 2019). Same answers apply that these are `subnormal` values, very close though not equal to 0.0f.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is for "[denormalized number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)".

Comment: Is this __bad__ or not really? What are the risks of when a variable starts taking on a #den value in your code?

Comment: @bobobobo, I have the same question. I wound up triggering #DEN with the following code
`-std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` I wound up replacing it with `std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()`

Answer (score 29):

Denormalized; too small (close to zero) to be represented as a number in the form 1.M * 2^E

Answer (score 5):

Denormal - too close to zero - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal